# I have problem to deploy my django project with docker nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

If I have running my containers on the server  side and everything is okay,for accessing route on the browser should I put ip of nginx container with domain in etc/host or it have to work without that?
my nginx.config

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name my_domain;

    root /code/;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/new_error.log debug;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /code/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /code/mediafiles/;
    }

}
```

where web is my docker-container with gunicorn running

Answer (score 0):

If your nginx container has the ports expose using the flag `-p <host_port>:<container_port>` you can access to nginx service adding the domain in your /etc/hosts file pointing to the ip of your localhost, however if you didn't use this flag you need pointing to the ip of your nginx container. What's the difference?...when you expose the ports you can use the service even outside of the host where the container was deployed.

I hope help you.